# Pokemon cards banned in unlimited

Tags: pokemon

In the new pokemon Ban List it says that FoGP and Archeops are banned in Expanded.

It kind of makes sense to say that, since they're not in Standard, but does that mean they're not banned in Unlimited?

i.e. am I allowed to make a deck with these cards if it was an unlimited deck?

Yes, I know they're not banned ***yet*** but you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

The list of banned cards on [Pokemon.com](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg-banned-card-list/) has a separate section listing the cards banned in Unlimited. Right now, there are no cards listed there.

Note that the Unlimited format consists of all cards that are, or ever have been, in Standard. [From Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unlimited_format_(TCG)):

> The Unlimited format of the Pokémon Trading Card Game allows any card that was once playable in Play! Pokémon tournaments [...] can be used.
>
> Because of the lack of restrictions in Unlimited, decks can use combinations of cards which are not legal in Standard format or Expanded format play. Cards such as Porygon2 and Seeker which never appeared in the same Standard format, are frequently used together.

So, if the cards you named were ever in the Standard rotation, and are not explicitly named in the 'Banned'-list under the 'Unlimited' header, you're good to build a deck around 'em.